# Sort javascript object key into array based on object's value

Tags: javascript

Let say I have an object with numbers as key and string as value

```
var obj = {
    '24': 'Sean',
    '17': 'Mary',
    '88': 'Andrew',
    '46': 'Kelvin'
}
```

Is there an easy way to sort the keys into an array based on their value where the result will looks like this:

```
[88,46,17,24]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
var obj = {
    '24': 'Sean',
    '17': 'Mary',
    '88': 'Andrew',
    '46': 'Kelvin'
}

var sortedKeys = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
  return obj[a].localeCompare(obj[b]);
}).map(Number)

console.log(sortedKeys)
```

Omit the `.map()` part if you are happy for the result to be an array of strings rather than numbers.

Further reading:

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)
- [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Convert_numeric_strings_to_numbers)

Or the same thing but with [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
const sortedKeys = Object.keys(obj)
                     .sort((a, b) => obj[a].localeCompare(obj[b]))
                     .map(Number)
```

Comment: Nice catch with the string values!

Comment: That was quick and nicely done. Just learn about [.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Phil - Thanks! I'll admit I didn't think of it to begin with, but when I ran my code without the `.map()` I happened to notice the strings in the output. I notice that other than that you independently came up with exactly the same thing except with arrow functions, which is certainly a lot neater assuming they're acceptable to the OP. Given that you deleted that answer I might add arrow functions to mine.

Comment: @nnnnnn no point having two identical answers and yours was first :). FYI, you can also convert the array to numeric via `.map(Number)`

Comment: @Phil - D'oh! I knew that, and in fact RobG had just mentioned it in a (now deleted) comment so I should've remembered. I'll edit that in.